# Docker container shows running even after exit command

Tags: docker

I am new to docker, hence may be missing a simple piece. Here is my scenario. I started a container with command 'docker run -it ubuntu:14.04'. Then with Ctrl+P+Q, I exited such that the container keeps running. I verified with docker ps, and saw the container running. Then I again entered the container with 'docker exec -it  bash. This took me inside the container again. Now on typing 'exit' command, I come out of the container, but the container is still in running mode. Normally with exit command, the container stops. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

The container's running status is tied to the initial process that it was created for/with.

If you do `docker run` then this will create a new container with some inital process. When that process terminates, the whole container is stopped. If that initial process was `bash`, and you `exit` it, then this terminates the container itself.

`docker exec` starts a new process inside of the running container. When that process terminates, the container still keeps running.

Typing `exit` into an interactive `bash` shell will just exit that shell. It will not affect other processes running inside the same container (just like closing one terminal window in your host OS does not affect any other processes).

Comment: Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

With the `exit` command in your case, the container stops only the `/bin/bash/` executable. Probably some other application like NGINX or Apache is running inside the container and does not let it shut down.